# Service port unavailable in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am defining

**1**: a Deployment for a pod running the official `rabbitmq` image

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        els-pod: rabbitmq
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: rabbitmq
        name: rabbitmq
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5672
      restartPolicy: Always
```

**2**: a Service as a wrapper, so that the pod(s) are discoverable

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbit
spec:
  ports:
  - name: rabbit-port
    port: 5672
    targetPort: 5672
  selector:
      els-pod: rabbit
```

I am logged in a container(pod):

```
/# nslookup rabbit
Server:     100.64.0.10
Address:    100.64.0.10#53

Name:   rabbit.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 100.71.124.222
```

**However**:

```
nc rabbit 5672 &> /dev/null; echo $?
1
```

The port is **NOT** open/accessible!

Is sth wrong with my manifests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service selector is incorrect. The pod has this metadata:

```
metadata:
  labels:
    els-pod: rabbitmq
```

But the service is looking for pods with this metadata

```
  selector:
      els-pod: rabbit
```

Change the selector to this

```
  selector:
      els-pod: rabbitmq
```

And it should work

Comment: an extra couple of eyes on stupid things blocking urgent work is always valuable ... thx!